# Unable to connect to a listening tcp port 80, Iptables is not blocking it

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, port, ss

I am trying to see if `tcp port 80` is open on a debian 11 server. I logged into it using SSH and did `curl -v telnet://localhost:80`. It says connection refused. If I do the same with port 22, it shows that I am connected to SSH service. Machine doesn't have telnet or netstat installed locally. It has ss and nc

The IP of the interface is `10.31.45.82` and the output of `sudo ss -antp` is:

```
Proto  State   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port
tcp    LISTEN  0       32      10.31.45.82:80      0.0.0.0:*          users:(("openvpn",pid=709,fd=7))
```

`curl -v telnet://10.31.45.82:80` is showing connection refused. Same with `nc 10.31.45.82 80`

I am not sure what is blocking the port. IP tables input chain has policy ACCEPT so that's not blocking the port. Any ideas? I am confused as to why localhost port 80 is showing as refused. Can an external firewall block telnet on localhost? I used nc localhost 22 and it's connecting to SSH and it shows `ESTAB in ss -antp`. But `nc localhost 80` is showing connection refused.

`sudo iptables-save -c` output:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [4958147:1463832998]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4920575:611816160]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
[185417:9902718] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
[185417:9902718] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[184273:9850974] -A FORWARD -o br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[256:13280] -A FORWARD -o br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -j DOCKER
[888:38464] -A FORWARD -i br-55d0dcfbc5d8 ! -o br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -j ACCEPT
[4:240] -A FORWARD -i br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -o br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -j ACCEPT
[4:176] -A DOCKER -d 172.22.0.3/32 ! -i br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -o br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT
[248:12864] -A DOCKER -d 172.10.0.3/32 ! -i br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -o br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[888:38464] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-55d0dcfbc5d8 ! -o br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[185417:9902718] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -j DROP
[888:38464] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
[185417:9902718] -A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Aug 13 16:58:44 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Aug 13 16:58:44 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [43383:2953292]
:INPUT ACCEPT [43379:2953052]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [137397:7281952]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [137648:7294828]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -d 10.31.45.83/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 123
[39282:2267543] -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[8:448] -A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
[6:456] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.22.0.0/16 ! -o br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.22.0.3/32 -d 172.22.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9001 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.22.0.3/32 -d 172.22.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -j RETURN
[5:228] -A DOCKER ! -i br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.22.0.3:9001
[248:12864] -A DOCKER ! -i br-55d0dcfbc5d8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.22.0.3:1883
COMMIT
```

And nftables not installed:

```
-bash: nftables: command not found
```

Comment: It could be due to a part not shown, or to nftables instead of iptables. You should supply *all* of `iptables-save -c` and `nftables list ruleset` (which might display back the content of iptables, or a separate content or both). Note: for localhost the result is to be expected.

Comment: Ok, I added the output of `iptables-save-c`. What do you mean by for the localhost, the result is to be expected?" I know localhost won't have port 80, does that mean that telnet will show connection refused? I am confused as to when telnet shows connection refused. Is it when a port is blocked or when a service is not present on a socket?

Comment: If the port is specifically listening for `10.31.45.82:80`, that means neither `127.0.0.1:80` nor `[::1]:80` will respond... and those two are what  `localhost:80` maps to.

Comment: connection refused with tcp initially means there is no application listening. Now, a firewall can mimic the same result so you can't know for sure. As for `nc 10.31.45.82 80` I have no idea why it's not working. Else, even if unrelated (udp not tcp rule), I notice is there a different IP address 10.31.45.83 elsewhere, is there a reason? Also even if I don't think there's something to find, my bad the command is `nft list ruleset` (not nftables). But it will display in an other form the rules from Docker etc.

Comment: The interface has two IP addresses.  The one that has last octet of 83 is doing port forwarding.

Comment: @telcoM Would the `nc` error on `localhost:80` be no response or connection refused because the port is not there? `nc` is giving connection refused. I am confused as to when there would be no response and when it would say connection refused.

Comment: I would expect a "connection refused" in that situation, as the kernel will see the incoming TCP SYN and send a RST in response: "This port is not open for connections, stop trying." Firewalls more commonly just drop the packet, causing the client to wait until timeout - but as A.B said, it is possible to configure a firewall to reject a connection the same way the kernel does it, in which case it may be indistinguishable.

Comment: @telcoM What I am confused is that can an external firewall block a `nc` attempt that's originating from the same server. I am logged into the server and doing `nc` of a port on that same server. Not checking if port is open from a remote host.

Comment: Yes, and if the application is listening in specific IP address only (as indicated by your `sudo ss -antp`), then the connection *must* be targeted to that specific IP, or else the kernel will refuse the connection. There are no external firewalls involved, it's just that the listening application is configured to accept connections in `10.31.45.82:80` and no other IP address. So `127.0.0.1:80` will not connect to that application in this case.